# How to store chat messages in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a chat application for my website! Now the question is how can i store chat messages on database! How to store chat messages of one specific person in database! Suppose there is a table
Username     Chat
John         Hello how are you?

In this case i can only store one message for one person! How can i store multiple message for one person? Suppose:
Username    Chat
John        Hello how are you?
            What's up?
            Just hanging around!

Please tell me how can i store the messages in database! And also please suggest should i store messages in database or text file?

Comment: Usually, database store like Username->John Message->Hello how are you? But i want to store multiple messages for one field like Username->John, <br/> Message->Hello how are you? <br />Hey There!<br />Love Stack Overflow<br /> Please tell me how can i store multiple messages for one filed i.e. Username!

Comment: You'd better learn from database schema basics. You have to design your schema carefully, as it may involve a lot of complicated relationships.

Comment: You have to maintain a table with chatId and chartStartTime and chartEndTime.  Create another table with ChatId as foreign key and enter the UserId and ChatDetails to it. Is this what you desired?

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Then is it possible to connect one field of one table to other field of another table, Nayas?

Comment: @Fred yes it is possible

Comment: Thank you, Nayas!

Comment: Make one tabel for message like chat_master
Fields :id,to_user_id,from_user_id,message,date_time,is_deleted,deleted_by

Comment: And please one more help! Suppose i have a comment system and when i type suppose Hello in comment then i echo it with php but what to do to store it permanently although the website is refreshed?

Comment: i can create table design for you, if it is required

Comment: I would love it! Please design the table, Nayas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design something like this

Tables

```
**ChatMaster** (Main table keep chat session details)
ChatId int identity, ChatStartTime datetime, ChatEndTime

**ChatDetails** (To keep chat message details and user from)
ChatDetailsId int identity, ChatMessage varchar(max), ChatId int foreign key, FromUserId int Foreign key, EntryTime datetime, IsActive bit

**ChatUsers** (to users) 
ChatUserId int identity, ChatDetailsId int foreign key, ToUserIds int foreign key
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for designing this!

Comment: check whether this helps you, please mark it as answer if it helps you

Comment: Yeah OK! It will take some time! And By the way which do you prefer, OP PHP OR PROCEDURAL PHP?

Comment: I mean OOP PHP or Procedural PHP

Comment: I am  not from php side. But i think Object Oriented Programming will help to you to better maintain the project.

Answer (score 6):

An example of a communication table for a chat

Primary key table username id
In the field replice message the tables edited

[image]